# "either" without using "of"

Tags: grammar, american-english

I intend to use "either" instead of "any" in an essay.
I was wondering if this is grammatically incorrect to say the following:
"Users could press either buttons of their stylus"

instead of following:
"Users could press either of the buttons ..."
?

Thanks

Comment: That's okay except that button is not plural. It would probably be better as " [...] either button **on** their stylus".

Comment: Also, I wouldn’t use _either_ unless there were only two buttons. If there were more than two buttons, I’d say, “Users could press **any** button on their stylus"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users could press either buttons ......

The sentence isn't correct.

You use the singular form of a countable noun in front of "either". If you want to use "of" after the either, you use the plural form of a noun.  So you can say:

Users could press either button......

Users could press either of the buttons.....

Both the sentences have the same meaning.